# Groups with presentation $\langle x_1,x_2,\dotsc, x_n\mid x_1^3, x_2^3,\dotsc, x_n^3\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I'm computer engineer but I'm working in some topics related with group theory. I found (accidentally) a group with presentation

$\langle x_1,x_2,\dotsc, x_n\mid x_1^3, x_2^3,\dotsc, x_n^3\rangle$

with some interesting topological properties (from the point of view of graph theory and automatic structures). My question is does this presentation belong to some family of groups? What happen if we change the exponent of relator?. What about the growth function of this group?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe knowing the presentation could help us

Comment: My apologies. I don't know why it doesn't appear. The presentation is <x_1, x_2, ... , x_ n|(x_1)^3, (x_2)^3, ..., (x^n)^3>. thanks.

Comment: This is $C_3 * C_3 * \ldots *C_3$, i.e. the free product of $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order $3$.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (spherical) growth function is $(1+2x)/(1-2(n-1)x)$.

Comment: Thanks, It is very helpful.